# Despite telling ssh to prompt only once on failure, I get two prompts from macOS servers - how do I prevent that

Tags: macos, ssh

I am getting asked twice to enter a password even though, if the password is wrong, I should only get asked once when using the `-o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1` option.

Try this:

On a Mac that has SSH access enabled, log in with an unknown user, and just press Return or enter any (wrong) password. Here's what you'll get:

```
$ ssh -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1 xxxx@localhost
Password:
xxxx@localhost's password: 
xxxx@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

What happens here is that you'll get prompted TWICE for the password, even though the "-o" argument asked to get only one prompt: Once it asks with the prompt text "Password:", and once with the text "xxxx@localhost's password:". The second one is the unwanted one.

On other (Linux) servers where I use the same command, I'd only get the single "Password:" prompt as desired.

What's causing the second prompt with the different text, and can I prevent that one on the client side, or only by fixing the sshd(?) config on the server's end?

I need this fixed because I'm writing a program for remote ssh logins, and I'm writing my own `SSH_ASKPASS` program for that, and I want to know ASAP if the password provided by my password helper was not valid. But with the above behavior, when logging into macOS computers, it would offer a second prompt before my main app even learns that it wasn't a valid password and a new one needs to be entered by the user first.

**Update**

I tried again with the verbose option:

```
ttsz370:~ tempi$ ssh -v -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1 xxxx@localhost
OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
...
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'xxxx'
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
...
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
xxxx@localhost's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
xxxx@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

So it seems that the first prompt is for "password", the second for "keyboard-interactive".

Some googling led me to one way to solve this:

If I also add -o PreferredAuthentications=password to the args, then I only get a single prompt.

However, this would mean that I'd have to specify ALL possible auth methods minus the "keyboard-interactive", because I don't know which methods the server may also support. And if it goes especially badly, then the server allows "keyboard-interactive" but not "password".

Is there a way to enquire which methods the host supports without having to log in first? There doesn't seem to exist a specific argument for the `ssh` command, but I wonder if I can get it with some other "trick", e.g. using verbose output but preventing the ssh to actually try to login after making the connection with the server?

Comment: Why don't you just use keys?

Comment: @MarcWilson Because I am writing a program that runs on other people's computers, and I have no control over what login methods they use